# Unable to acquire tokens for multiple resources simultaneously through Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application where I am trying to acquire tokens for both Power BI and Microsoft Graph API simultaneously using the below mentioned code snippet.

```cs
AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(signedInUserID));

//Getting Power BI token
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
   code,
   new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
   credential, 
   pbiResourceID);

//Getting Graph token
AuthenticationResult graphResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
  code, 
  new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), 
  credential, 
  graphResourceId);
```

The request for acquiring token from Graph API is failing with error:

> AADSTS50079: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. You should be able to use the refresh token received from the first one to get the second one. http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799868/login-to-azure-web-application-fails-with-aadsts50079-the-user-is-required-to/45803513?noredirect=1#comment78647129_45803513.

Comment: As I said over there this means when you're using the refresh token to get an access token for a new resource, the end user has not fulfilled the MFA requirement.  You'll need to perform an interactive request (through OWIN OpenId Connect middleware in your case) specifying the resource that failed.  The other option is to extra the *claims* parameter out of the error, and stick that in the new request with OWIN as `claims=<CLAIMS_BODY>`.

Comment: For docs on this issue, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-conditional-access-developer